# Trying to get access to my .NET ClickOnce application over Internet with integrated windows authentication

Tags: .net, windows, authentication, clickonce, integrated

I have created a ClickOnce application and published it on my homepage in a subfolder on my server which is in a local network with my PC. I have set the authentication to integrated windows authentication and created two new user accounts. The first account equates my private PC. With my PC I can easily access the publish.htm and install the application.

In future it is necessary that other users have access to the setup. Therefore i have three tablet PC's which are all connected to a domain. My PC and server are private and have nothing to do with the domain.

I have tried for hours to get access to my homepage with one of the tablets, but it still doesnt work. I think the reason is the user account i created. I simply used the login name and password like i did it for my PC.

I am not very familiar with domains, so i dont have an idea how to get it work or if it's even possible. The main goal is no just a working installation. I'd like to use the update function of ClickOnce over the internet but wihout allowing access to everyone.

Has anybody an idea? I'm a little desperated and would be happy i someone could help me.